# How to revert intel-microcode

Tags: linux, boot, firmware

A couple of days ago I received an update notification for intel-microcode and duly installed the update. Prior to that, I was getting clear (cold) boots. By this I mean that errant "^[k" strings (without quotes) were not intermittently auto-generated during the boot up process. By intermittent I mean these strings:

1. would appear during one (cold) boot but not another;
2. would prepend random lines of boot up text;
3. would auto-generate different numbers of those strings on random text lines during the boot up.

I did not get this misbehaviour when I used the previous Kubuntu 22.04.2 but am getting this with the current Kubuntu 22.04.3. I am wondering if the recent intel-microcode update has a connection to this as I had managed to stabilise the system prior to that update.

I have preformed an "apt-cache policy intel-microcode" and found the following.

```
$ apt-cache policy intel-microcode
intel-microcode:
  Installed: 3.20230808.0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Candidate: 3.20230808.0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.20230808.0ubuntu0.22.04.1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.20210608.2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

How do I revert the microcode back to version "3.20210608.2ubuntu1 500" as I suspect that the microcode update may contain code that is "too new" for this Core i3 laptop?

Comment: `# apt install intel-microcode=3.20210608.2ubuntu1`

Comment: I very doubt it is a cause of microcode. In any case, the microcode is loaded at CPU initialization (or later). Disable the package (or reinstall an old one) and reboot, and so you get no microcode or old one (or the one provided by BIOS). -- And microcode CPU (exact model) specific. The loader will check the correct one out of the many hundreds there is in the packages (and CPU will not load microcode of wrong CPU family/model/series)

Comment: I would actually guess this is a problem with your keyboard.  `^[k` looks like the character sequences displayed when special keys like arrows, page-up, etc, are pressed and echoed when an application is not expecting to process them.  (Try doing `cat >/dev/null` and bang on your keyboard, and you'll see them.)  Maybe one of your keys is stuck, or needs to be cleaned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install version 3.20210608.2ubuntu1, specify it using `=`:

```
sudo apt install intel-microcode=3.20210608.2ubuntu1
```

The microcode package contains many different microcode updates, which are applied to your CPU depending on what model it is; so it’s unlikely that you would get an update applied that’s “too new” for your CPU. It’s also unlikely that a microcode update would result in the symptoms you describe, but reverting as above will allow you to determine that and you can always upgrade back to the latest version.

If you want to *avoid* future updates after reverting, you can put a hold on the package:

```
sudo apt-mark hold intel-microcode
```

Comment: Thank you for such a swift response. You have supplied both parts of the answer that I need.  Excellent!!

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the Kernel only updates the microcode if the Kernel has a *later* revision of the microcode than the BIOS.

If you run `dmesg|grep -i microcode` the output can indicate if the Kernel has updated the microcode.

E.g. the following example from Ubuntu 18.04 was when the BIOS had an earlier    revision of the `Xeon E5 v3` microcode than the revision `0x49` than in the `intel-microcode` package, and so the Kernel updated the microcode as indicated by the `microcode updated early to revision 0x49` message:

```
$ dmesg|grep -i microcode
[    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x49, date = 2021-08-11
[    1.749574] microcode: sig=0x306f2, pf=0x1, revision=0x49
[    1.750009] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.
```

Whereas after applying a BIOS update which included microcode revision `0x49` the Kernel was no longer updating the microcode:

```
$ dmesg|grep microcode
[    1.750130] microcode: sig=0x306f2, pf=0x1, revision=0x49
[    1.750515] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.
```

I.e. on the problematic machine you should be able to tell if the Kernel is actually updating the microcode for your processor.